# Wordpress: How can I create an external page or file that contains posts with 1 specific category?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, categories

I'm developing a blog and custom theme with WordPress. My homepage has the 5 most recent posts with 4 `div`s. Each `div` has a specific title like 'Personal Stories' or 'Tutorials'. I have created, within the WordPress manager, the 4 corresponding categories. I am quite new to PHP and WordPress in general, and I was wondering if it was possible to somehow add an anchor to each of those 4 `div`s; that link to an external page with a list of posts with those specific categories?

I've tried creating new PHP files and linking the `index.php` file to them with an `<a>` tag, but I just simply get an '**ERROR 404**'. I was hoping to implement 'The Loop' on these pages and filter the posts to just those with a specific category.

I've also tried using WordPress functions that create a URL with the category ID. As the `div`s do not have categories, I manually find them. In the end, I get something like this:

```
<a href="<?php get_category_link( 3 ); ?>">
<div id='story' class='circle'>
    <p class='text'><br>People Stories</p>
</div>
</a>
```

And this is assuming that the number '3' is the ID I found when manually checking the categories.

Comment: I don't know I'm badly english or your wishes not clearly :(. I can't understand.

Comment: Just create `category.php` and this will be your template that will show posts from single category term. Check [this post](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) out. Also I recommend that you scour on the https://developer.wordpress.org/ you can find a lot of explanation there.

Comment: If you wanted to do the pure URL route -- example.com/?cat=3 gets you the archive of all category 3 posts

Comment: @dingo_d By the way, [codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/) is a much better resource than [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/). It's unfortunate that they replaced some codex pages with the new developer pages. Those new pages are so empty of content, that they are almost useless.

Comment: The developer ones should be 'official' iirc. The old codex ones were maintained by users, and you could find some examples that were bad practice iirc. This is the reason why more and more articles are transferred to developers site. I also liked codex pages more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 
I added a

```
<a href="?cat=3">
<div id='#' class='#'>
    <p class='#'>...</p>
</div>
</a>
```

When I clicked on the <div>, it took me to the category**.**php page.

Thank you